# Problema con RecyclerView en Android

Tags: android, android-layout, recyclerview

Estoy tratando de implementar una lista con un `RecyclerView` cuyo adaptador se alimenta de un cursor. No entiendo por qué al ejecutar la app, la lista muestra solo el primer elemento aunque en la tabla de la base datos tengo 7 registros. Revisé todo lo que pude y lo único que encontré fue que en el `layout` del ítem el `TextView` tenía la propiedad `layout_height="match_parent"` y la cambié a `wrap_content` pero el comportamiento no cambió.
Cualquier comentario será bienvenido. Gracias.

XML del RecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/lista"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

XML del Item

```
<TextView
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hola mundo"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    />

<TextView
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:id="@+id/listanombre"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:padding="10dp"
    />

<View style="@style/Divider"/>
```

Adapter

```
public class ListaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListaAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    Context myContext;
    CursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;

    public ListaAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor){
        myContext=context;

        myCursorAdapter = new CursorAdapter(myContext,cursor,0) {
            @Override
            public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
                View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
                return retView;
            }

            @Override
            public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
                TextView textView  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                TextView listanombre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listanombre);
                textView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));
                listanombre.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(2))));
            }
        };
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        myCursorAdapter.getCursor().moveToPosition(position);
        myCursorAdapter.bindView(holder.itemView,myContext,myCursorAdapter.getCursor());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myCursorAdapter.getCount();
    }


    public static class  ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView textView,listanombre;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            listanombre = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.listanombre);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: seria, un poco mas facil si pusieras el xml del recycler, al igual que el adapter donde estas usando dicho elemento

Comment: Agregado, muchas gracias.

Comment: Deberías poner la actividad donde está tu recycler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Te faltó poner el elemento xml padre de los `TextView` del ítem. Debería tener el `height="wrap_content"`. Es probable que lo tengas en `"match_parent"` y por eso el ítem este ocupando toda la pantalla.

Comment: Era eso precisamente! muchas gracias. El elemento padre es un LinearLayout que efectivamente tenía el layout_height="match_parent"